# Add Node to Entity Reference

Tags: entities

I have two content types, one called Task the other called Task List. Task List uses entity reference field to let users create multiple lists of any Task on the website. I'm using the entity reference module versus flags because I want the user to add addition content to the Task List page.

I'm looking for a way to let users, while on any task page (especially other user's tasks), add that task to any Task List they've created.

So essentially click "add" on a Task page which would then display a list of the user's own Task Lists. Then select one of their lists which would add the Task to the Task List's entity reference field.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So you want a convenient way to edit entity reference field without entering node edit page? I'm afraid it's not directly possible now and you will need to get your hands dirty. But it would be a nice feature request in Entity Reference issue queue. In the meantime, see [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/90871/16495) - it shows how to set values in code. I hope it will at least guide you into the right direction. I'll leave form implementation to you ;)